# What is the default scope for bean in spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working with SpringMVC .Every thing going good but I have some doubts

1)What is the default scope for SpringMVC

2)What is the differnce between @pathvarible,@RequestParam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default scope is singleton.

Given the URL `/foo/bar/1/bing?blam=zing`, `1` could be a path variable value (it's part of the path), and `zing` could be a request parameter value:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{barId}/bing")
public void handle(@PathVariable("barId") Long barId, @RequestParam("blam") blamParameter) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have made a typo - '@PathParam', correct to '@PathVariable', please :)

Comment: You better, it was extremely difficult :)